# Java to Android Code

Tags: java, android, ssl, network-programming, client

I have coded this client ssl code for java which works great and sends the wave file to a server. I am trying now to change or use this code on Android but I am having problems doing so. The questions that I have are things such as:

1. How do I set the pathStore and trustStoreFile(which directories are these on the android)?
2. Where do I upload the certificate file to(trustStoreFile) ?
3. Are there any settings that I need to configure?
4. Is this code what I need to use to accomplish the task of sending the wav file to the server that is listening? 
   Thanks so much ! 
   Please Help !

Here is the ssl client code in :

```
package admir.network.ssl.client;

import android.provider.Settings;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;


import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;


//import com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext;
//import com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
//import com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManager;


public class test2 {

    private static final String HOST = "X.X.X.X";

    private static final int PORT = 5000;
    String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    final static String pathToStores = System.setProperty("user.dir","user.dir"+"/java/admir.network.ssl.client/");
    final static String trustStoreFile = "cert.jks" ; // filename
    public String app = System.setProperty("user.dir",pwd);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String trustFileName = pathToStores + "/" + trustStoreFile;
        char[] passphrase = "xxxxx".toCharArray();
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(trustFileName), passphrase);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
        Socket s = sf.createSocket(HOST, PORT);

        String FILE_TO_SEND = ""+ System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+"src"+"/"+"Voice 005.wav"+"";

        File soundFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile(FILE_TO_SEND);

        if (s.isBound()){
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(soundFile);
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            System.out.println("Done Sending.");
            out.close();
        }

        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: See the Android tutorial [Security with HTTPS and SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), including the links near the end under the topic ["Client Certificates"](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#ClientCert).

Comment: File I/O is very different on Android. You don't store files within class packages, but within the resource folder `/res/` of a wider android structure. These can be accessed via a call to `Context.getResource(int i);`.

Comment: @AlexT. - Files in `/res` can only be added at build time. If OP wants to add a certificate at run time, it needs to go somewhere else.

Comment: @TedHopp where does the certificate need to go specifically? and how do i point to it>?

Comment: @Aboogie - That's up to you. You can initialize a `KeyStore` from any `InputStream`, so you could package it as a resource as Alex suggests, or use any number of other ways. See the docs on the [Android Keystore System](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). You can also find a lot of posts on the web (such as [this one](http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/)) that walk through using Android's security framework.